# To create div link in li of toplinks in magento

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink

I am using latest version of magento and i want to create div tag into li of toplinks in magento for cart link only.
How can i do it? 
For class I have added

```
<liParams><class>mini-top-cart</class></liParams>
```

but its also not working

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create one div with class mini-top-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to put some design changes only on the My Cart Link in the top links then you can easily do without mentioning a div class and just changing the 'a' class which is defined as "top-link-cart" by default. So if you override the Links block placed under core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php and move it to you local folder for future proofing and then in the function addCartLink() change the $parentBlock defined at the bottom to have your own class, it will look something like :

```
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
```

replace it with your own class for eg mini top cart.

```
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="mini-top-cart"');
```

Once done with that you can easily style your a class in your css by adding

```
a.mini-top-cart {
your styles here }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: just in case refer to this post to override a core block:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14692/